# Is it possible to resize video in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

I took a screen recording from my iPhone 5 and I want to convert its size from 640x1136 to 750x1134. For extra pixels I need black fill color. Is it possible in iMovie in OS X?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to produce that exact resolution in iMovie 10, because it doesn't support custom resolutions. The only resolutions you can export a video project to are:

- 480p: 854x480
- 540p: 960x540
- 720p: 1280x720
- 1080p: 1920x1080

Note that all of these are 16:9 (1.778) whereas the target you're after is about 3:2 (1.66).

You can certainly add black borders or otherwise crop/frame videos in iMovie, so it *could* be a stepping stone to another tool. But It's probably not the tool you want if that precise output format is required.

Also remember that many video *players* will automatically resize and add black borders on *playback* to best fit the screen's aspect ratio.

Comment: I only see these options for resolution: 540p, 720p and 1080p.

Comment: Yes, why o why is there not a 360p (640x360) export option? Exceedingly annoying.